# Apache airflow: No module name 'airflow'

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to apache airflow and I am following the example code at:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py

I copied and pasted the code found in the link above in an `example.py` inside a folder on my desktop.

The initial code is:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
```

If I run `python example.py`, I get the error:

> > from airflow import DAG

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'

Even if I installed airflow as follows:

`pip install apache-airflow`

What can be a possible solution?

Comment: I am trying to do the same but seeing this error:
```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.operators.bash'

```

I did `pip install apache-airflow`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running:

```
pip install \
 apache-airflow==1.10.10 \
 --constraint \
        https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/1.10.10/requirements/requirements-python3.7.txt
```

Worked for me. Check here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/installation.html